# Is there really no secret stream copy method in the Java runtime?

Tags: java

I know about IOUtils and I know about FileChannel transferTo.
But I would really like to know if there is a stream copy method somewhere hidden in the normal Java runtime.

Something like public long copy( InputStream is, OutputStream os){...}

I know I can write it myself but I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no "secret" method / facility for doing this in the Java runtime libraries.  If there was, you shouldn't use it.

---

Secret methods ... aka private APIs ... are typically implemented that way for a good reason.  For example, they may have behaviour that is not what is wanted in a general purpose API.  This is often a good reason to avoid them.

Furthermore, Sun/Oracle has always taken the position that these APIs and/or their behaviors are liable to be changed or removed **without notice**.  And indeed, this happens.

Finally, many IDEs, bug / style checkers and dependency management frameworks will get stroppy with you<sup>*</sup> if your code depends directly on the private APIs.

<sup>* Look it up :-)</sup>